# How to get Single Row From Query without a foreach Loop?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

There  is table `ViewRight` in my database with three columns:

1. user_id (FK- int)
2. folder_id(PK-int)
3. folder_name(varchar(MAX))

I wrote query in c# code to get values of table. I wrote this query below to get values from 
`ViewRight` table of provided `user_id`.

`var query2 = from p in dbContext.ViewRights  where p.user_id==user_id select p;`

**Question** I have to use foreach loop to get value of folder_id value of and folder_name of provided user_id. this foreach loop has single value. I don't want to use `foreach loop` for single value. I there any other approach to get this without using foreach loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only gonna be one record returned. `var query2 = (from p in dbContext.ViewRights where p.user_id==user_id select p).FirstOrDefault()`;

Comment: Ryan is it possible to add result of this query into List ?

Comment: What are you wanting to add to a list? But either an individual element or the entire record should be able to be added to a list fairly easy.

Comment: if there are two values then?

Comment: should i make another ticket for this question?

Comment: I think your ok asking it here, Just show me an example of what your kind of trying to do.

Comment: ok. here `var query2 = from p in dbContext.ViewRights where p.user_id==user_id select p;`   it is returning two values. how to get these two without using `foreach loop`  
                    `

Comment: query2[0] and query2[1] if you know there is just gonna be two.

Comment: hmm at that point I would use a loop of some sort, but I know you said you didn't want to use one.

Answer (score 2):

Use `var vr = query2.SingleOrDefault(x => x.user_id == userid);
if(vr != null) Console.WriteLine(vr.folder_id);`

I can't believe John Saunders just copied my answer!

Comment: null ref check added.

Comment: John included a null reference check. Now that you have done the same (though brackets would make it easier to see), I will remove my downvote.

Answer (score 2):

```
var vr = query2.SingleOrDefault(x => x.user_id == userid); 
if (vr != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(vr.folder_id);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

.SingleOrDefault will get one or more count records

use

.FirstOrDefault();

i chose .FirstOrDefault

Comment: Please explain SingleOrDefault better.

Comment: That's not what SingleOrDefault will do.